# Rails Environment Variable Not Getting Set on Production on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, delayed-job, mailgun

I am trying to setup ActionMail using Mailgun and DelayedJob on Heroku and I've got everything working to the point where DelayedJob is initiating the request with Mailgun, but I'm getting a `400 Bad Request: 'from' parameter is missing` from Mailgun.

My mailer is `app/mailers/example_mailer.rb`:

```
class ExampleMailer < ApplicationMailer

def sample_email(user)
    @user = user
    mailgun_client = Mailgun::Client.new ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY']
    message_params = {:from     => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
                      :to       => @user.email,
                      :subject  => 'Sample Mail Using Mailgun API',
                      :text     => 'Testing...'}

    mailgun_client.send_message ENV['MAILGUN_DOMAIN'], message_params

  end
end
```

My `config/application.yml`:

```
MAILGUN_API_KEY:  '[REDACTED]'
MAILGUN_ADDRESS:  'smtp.mailgun.org'
MAILGUN_PORT:     587
MAILGUN_DOMAIN:   '[REDACTED]'
MAILGUN_USERNAME: '[REDACTED]'
MAILGUN_PASSWORD: '[REDACTED]'
GMAIL_USERNAME:   '[REDACTED]'
```

So since the error is that the from field isn't being set properly I logged into my heroku console and tested my `ENV` variables and lo and behold all of them are present except `ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME']`. Is there any reason why this variable would be missing in my production environment? I'm not sure how to debug this as I've never come across a problem with environment variables like this before.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot, I setup figaro to handle my environment variables and forgot to publish them to heroku:

```
figaro heroku:set -e production
```

Also, you need to wrap all variables in application.yml in strings, so I also had to update the MAILGUN_PORT to '587'.